# Distributeload cloning flowfile and sending double

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a NIFI DistributeLoad processor that sends to an executestreamcommand processor. The issue I am seeing is that the distributeload processor is creating a clone and sending the original plus the clone to the executestreamcommand processor. This is not happening for all the files I send through. Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: I can't recreate this problem.. Which NiFi version do you use & what is the Processor's configuration?

Comment: distributeload processor with 4 for number of relationships and next available for distribution strategy.

Comment: Could you update your question with your `nifi flow screenshot`?

Comment: and again, which NiFi version?

Comment: it's version 0.7.1. Figured out that it must have something to do with how distributeload processor handles the removal of relationships. I used to have 8 relationships going out of that processor and changed it to 4 and I think that's when i started seeing the clones. I had to recreate the processor and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's version 0.7.1. Figured out that it must have something to do with how distributeload processor handles the removal of relationships. I used to have 8 relationships going out of that processor and changed it to 4 and I think that's when i started seeing the clones. I had to recreate the processor and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed - Didn't even change the number of outbound relationships - just rewired them and started getting duplicate entries.

Replaced the processor with a new one and duplicates have disappeared. Will raise a bug.